# how to handle excel files using C++?

Tags: c++, excel, file-handling

I'm new to C++, And I want to enter values into an `excel` spreadsheet using C++, I know we can handle files using `fstream` but how to get a specific column or row using this method.

Comment: Essentially, modern MS Office formats are zip archives of xml files. You can work on that XML like on any other (i.e., with a suitable library).

Comment: In theory you start by reading the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-xlsx/f780b2d6-8252-4074-9fe3-5d7bc4830968, in practice that's a horrendous task and probably not worth to do in C++. Excel macros are a powerful tool and you can program anything you want with them as well.

Comment: Yes you can either dig deep into hacking the Excel file structures or just to write your whole table as .csv text file and import it to Excel.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen How horrendous it is depends on what you want to do. But yes, Visual Basic is best suited for the task; next best is probably another .net language, e.g. C#. You could also try to do something simpler, like custom XML that's then *transformed* into .xlsx, or into a simpler spread sheet format that Excel can understand (CSV??). But of course, the need to manipulate office files from C++ programs may legitimately exist because both ends of the equation are prerequisites.

Comment: Voted to close as SO is not for library recommendations but see [this dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892295/writing-an-excel-spread-sheet-in-c) for options.

Comment: TBH. This sounds like an uphill struggle if you are "new to C++".  There are open source libraries around for reading .xlsx files from C++ (I won't recommend one, as I haven't tried them). Or you can 'drive' the Excel application itself using COM (#import statement in MSVC C++). Or use VBA. Or use Python etc etc. Your language choice should take into account what else you might want to do later, as presumably reading and writing Excel files is only part of the project?

Comment: In order to get the answers that help you most provide as many details as possible. You can already see that "many ways lead to Rome". Which approach would serve you best strongly depends on your specific use case. The most important questions are probably: Are you really bound to C++? Do you really need to support the native Excel file format (or can you just use [CSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180))? Related: What exactly is your task? Just plain data in rows (then CSV is good) or formulas and macros (then you need a proper spreadsheet format)? Add that to your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to persist in using C++ (despite the comments above), this sample will give you an idea of the coding work needed to use C++ to automate the Excel application (as you might do in VBA or C#) rather than manipulate the file using a known file format (using a third-party library). The sample opens an existing worksheet in the background, adds 1 to the value in cell A1 on Sheet1, and then saves it.

Whether this is a suitable or efficient solution for your case will depend on what exactly you are trying to do with the files.

**NB. Only works with the MS Visual Studio compiler.**

The hard-coded paths to the import libraries may be different on your computer, and may depend on your Excel version.

```
//Import all the type libraries

#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.dll" \
    rename("RGB","RGB_mso") rename("DocumentProperties","DocumentProperties_mso") 

using namespace Office;

#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"

using namespace VBIDE;

#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" \
    rename( "DialogBox", "ExcelDialogBox" ) \
    rename( "RGB", "ExcelRGB" ) \
    rename( "CopyFile", "ExcelCopyFile" ) \
    rename( "ReplaceText", "ExcelReplaceText" ) \
    exclude( "IFont", "IPicture" )

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
  
    Excel::_ApplicationPtr pXL;
    if (FAILED(pXL.CreateInstance("Excel.Application")))
    {
        cout << "Could not create instance of Excel" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try
    {
        //Uncomment this to see what is going on during each step
        //pXL->Visible = true;

        Excel::_WorkbookPtr pWb = pXL->Workbooks->Open(L"c:\\temp\\testbook.xlsx");

        //Gets number from cell A1 in Sheet1 and increments
        Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = pWb->Worksheets->Item[L"Sheet1"];
        Excel::RangePtr pRng = pSheet->Cells;
        _variant_t val = pRng->Item[1][1];
        double dVal{ val };
        pRng->Item[1][1] = ++dVal;

        pWb->Save();
        pWb->Close();
    }    
    catch (_com_error ce) 
    {
        cout << "Something went wrong" << endl;
        _bstr_t bstrDesc = ce.Description();
        if( ! bstrDesc )
        {
            cout << "  Unknown Error" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "  Error text: " << bstrDesc << endl;
        }
    }

    pXL->Quit();
}
```

EDIT: In answer to the unspoken question why is it Excel::_ApplicationPtr, Excel::_WorkbookPtr etc, but for a Range it is Excel::RangePtr (no _)? Absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenXLSX](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX) is a great library for reading and writing excel sheets using C++. Its API documentation is not in the Github repo. It can be found [here](https://troldal.github.io/openxlsx.html). The examples in the repo are quite extensive and detailed. Build instructions are also straightforward.

I have tried it on Linux and Windows (with MinGW). It works great and has the same behavior on both OSs.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is probably no the best choice to use if you want to manipulate `.xlsx` files. You would be better off either using macros in Excel using VBA, or you can write an Excel plugin using VSTO. If you really need to stick with C++, consider if you really need native Excel format. Maybe just `.csv` file be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

to deal data with excel in c++ you can use the CSV format comma separated  values to overwrite data in excel I have also made a project  related to this problem you can check
[you can click on the GitHub repo to check how it is working](https://github.com/askarikzm/PF-Final-project-Banking-system-in-C-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35559884)